# How do i change string value with strcpy in c

Tags: c, strcpy

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char str1[100];
    char str2[100]; 

    printf("(1) input str1: ");
    scanf_s("%s", str1, sizeof(str1));
    printf("    input str2: ");
    scanf_s("%s", str2, sizeof(str2));

    strcpy_s(str2,100,str1);
    printf("(2) exchange str1=%s str2=%s\n", str1, str2);
    printf("len1=%d len2=%d\n", strlen(str1), strlen(str2));
```

i would change str1 to str2 each other.

At first i'd written 'strcpy_2(str2,str1)', But VS said i need more parameter,
so i wrote 'strcpy_s(str2,100,str1).

Although error isn't founded, the result is wrong.
str1 and str2 has same value about str1.

What is my problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you allowed to use a temporary string? It might be worth the speed of `memcpy` just to do that.

Comment: You're only copying once. How could that possibly interchange the strings?

Comment: Copy `str2` to a temporary string, copy `str1` to `str2`, then copy the temporary string to `str1`. That's the usual method for any kind of swap.

Comment: Thank you Barmar. I made a big mistake. Have a good day

Comment: You could also use an XOR loop over the strings. So you wouldn't need a temp string.

Comment: @Neil Why do you think is `memcpy()` faster than `strcpy()`?

Comment: @thebusybee see this discussion on [memcpy _vs_ strcpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24966693/is-memcpy-usually-faster-than-strcpy). Xor loop is `O(1)` space, but I imagine testing for equality would be a major slowdown.

Comment: @Neil As I thought, this is **not a general** rule, as the accepted answer shows. It depends heavily on the target system and the implementation of these library functions. -- Anyway, replacing `strcpy()` by `memcpy()` in this case is bad: the data to copy are strings, and the may-be-or-not advantage of some microseconds in the context of human input is not worth this loss of source code clarity. There is little worse than premature optimization. I would only do this if the requested performance cannot reached otherwise.

Comment: Agreed, there is so little data here that clarity of intent should be preferred. @KimByeongHwa if you get it working, I think answering your own question is appropriate, explaining your thought process. That way people with the same problem can search for it.