# strcmp in Intel x86 with cmpsb

Tags: assembly, x86, strcmp

I want to code a `strcmp` in nasm x86. The main problem is when it has to return a negative value. I've tried the following, but in many cases it just returns a wrong value.

I'm calling it from C, like: `strcmp("abc", "abd")` and I expect an `int` to be returned.

```
strcmp:
push ebp
mov ebp, esp

cld

xor eax, eax
mov esi, [ebp+0x8]
mov edi, [ebp+0xc]
mov ecx, -1

strcmp_loop:
cmp byte [esi], 0
jz strcmp_end

repe cmpsb
dec esi
dec edi

strcmp_end:
mov al, byte [esi]
sub al, byte [edi]
jns strcmp_ret
neg al
neg eax
strcmp_ret:
pop ebp
ret
```

The double `neg` is to handle negative values, otherwise it returns `255` instead of `-1` and so on.

Comment: What does it return in that case?

Comment: **`repe cmpsb` implements `memcmp`, not `strcmp`**.  If the strings are equal out to the terminating 0 byte, `repe cmpsb` will keep going until it finds a difference in whatever comes next, or gets to an unmapped page and segfaults.  Your whole approach is flawed, regardless slow branch sign-extension.  You'd have to `strlen` one of your inputs first, with `repne scasb`.  But don't do that because it's slow, and so is `repe cmpsb`.  [Fast Strings microcode only applies to `rep stos/movs`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33480999)

Comment: `movsx eax, al` would be much more efficient.