# x86 rep prefix with a count of zero: what happens?

Tags: assembly, x86, instruction-set

What happens for an initial count of zero for an x86 `rep` prefix?

[Intel's manual](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rep:repe:repz:repne:repnz) says explicitly it’s a `while count != 0` loop with the test at the top, which is the sane expected behaviour.

But most of the many vague reports I’ve seen elsewhere suggest that there’s no initial test for zero so it would be like a countdown with a test at the end and so disaster if it’s `repeat` `{… count —=1; }` `until count == 0;` or who knows.

Comment: I put in an explicit conditional branch at the top and I would love to remove it if I can.

Comment: z80 had no initial test for its string instructions, maybe you heard it in that context?

Comment: I’m an old Z80 professional asm programmer. So maybe fear has remained in my heart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing happens with RCX=0; `rep` prefixes *do* check for zero first like the pseudocode says.  (Unlike the `loop` instruction which is [exactly like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46881279/how-exactly-does-the-x86-loop-instruction-work/46881622#46881622) the bottom of a `do{}while(--ecx)`, or a `dec rcx`/`jnz` but without affecting FLAGS.)

I think I've heard of this rarely being used as an idiom for a conditional load [or store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670916/how-does-x86-handle-store-conditional-instructions) with `rep lodsw` or `rep stosw` with a count of 0 or 1, especially in the bad old days before cmov.  (`cmov` is an unconditional load feeding an ALU select operation, so it needs a valid address, unlike `rep lods` with a count of zero.)  This is not efficient especially for `rep stos` on modern x86 with Fast Strings microcode (P6 and later), especially without anything like Fast Short Rep-Movs (Ice Lake IIRC.)  Golden Cove (Alder Lake / Sapphire Rapids) additionally has fast zero-length `rep movsb` which makes that the same speed as 1-128 bytes, making it not terrible for use-cases that sometimes do a zero length memcpy.

The same applies for instructions that treat the prefixes as `repz` / `repnz` (cmps/scas) instead of unconditional `rep` (lods/stos/movs).  Doing zero iterations means they leave FLAGS umodified.

If you want to check FLAGS after a `repe/ne cmps/scas`, you need to make sure the count was non-zero, or that FLAGS was already set such that you'll branch in a useful way for zero-length buffers.  (Perhaps from xor-zeroing a register that you're going to want later.)

---

`rep movs` and `rep stos` have fast-strings microcode on CPUs since P6, but the startup overhead makes them rarely worth it, especially when sizes can be short and/or data might be misaligned.  They're more useful in kernel code where you can't freely use XMM registers.  Some recent CPUs like Ice Lake have fast-short-rep microcode that I think is supposed to reduce startup overhead for small counts.

`repe/ne scas/cmps` do *not* have fast-strings microcode on most CPUs, only on very recent CPUs like Sapphire Rapids and maybe Alder Lake P-cores.  So they're quite slow, like one load per clock cycle (so 2 cycles per count for `cmpsb/w/d/q`) according to testing by https://agner.org/optimize/ and https://uops.info/.

- [What setup does REP do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33902068/what-setup-does-rep-do)
- [Why is this code using strlen heavily 6.5x slower with GCC optimizations enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55563598/why-is-this-code-using-strlen-heavily-6-5x-slower-with-gcc-optimizations-enabled) - GCC `-O1` used to use `repne scasb` to inline `strlen`.  This is a disaster for long strings.
- [Which processors support "Fast Short REP CMPSB and SCASB"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75309389/which-processors-support-fast-short-rep-cmpsb-and-scasb) (very recent feature)
- [Enhanced REP MOVSB for memcpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43343231/enhanced-rep-movsb-for-memcpy) - even without ERMSB, `rep movs` will use no-RFO stores for large sizes, similar to NT stores but not bypassing the cache.  Good general Q&A about memory bandwidth considerations.

---

For conditional load / store, APX will also introduce a way to do that *efficiently* and branchlessly, with scalar instead of AVX2 or AVX-512 masking: a fault-suppressing (Conditionally-Faulting) `cfcmovcc [mem], reg` as well as a load form.  See *[Hard to debug SEGV due to skipped cmov from out-of-bounds memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54050188/hard-to-debug-segv-due-to-skipped-cmov-from-out-of-bounds-memory)* for some about that and other conditional-load things x86 supports.

Comment: `repe` and `repne` both work the same way, if the counter is initially zero then the repeated instructions are skipped without any effect. **Importantly**, the flags are not modified by a `cmps` or `scas` instruction skipped in this way. So if you want to branch on eg the Zero Flag then you have to make sure that the counter is never zero initially, or that the Zero Flag is pre-initialised the way you want, eg in https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/ldebug/file/eb3730a8118e/source/expr.asm#l3505

Comment: @ecm: Thanks, I think the FLAGS-unmodified possible gotcha was what I was trying to remember as being "special" about a count of zero for rep[n]e cmps/scas.  Update.

Comment: Strange, I could have sworn that `rep` when `cx=0` didn't terminate immediately but rather wrapped around to `ffff...` and had to reach zero again.

Comment: @puppydrum64 No, the `rep` type prefixes do "check" for a zero counter initially. This is why the pseudo-code in https://pushbx.org/ecm/doc/insref.htm#insSCASB and the other string instructions start with `jcxz` (for `a16`) before the loop, instead of only including a `loop` branch. Of course that isn't a good source because I added those examples, but I believe the vendor manuals by AMD or Intel would confirm this. Or try it in a debugger.

Comment: Chances are I'm also getting x86 and Z80 mixed up, I tend to do that very often.

Comment: Worth noting that intel added a "Fast Zero Length REP MOVSB" feature with the Golden Cove architecture. "REP MOVSB performance of zero length operations is enhanced. The latency of a zero length REP MOVSB is now the same as the latency of lengths 1 to 128 bytes". On earlier architectures it seems beneficial to add a branch and skip the movs/stos if the length is 0.